# Superconductivity in ceramics

Tags: superconductivity

[image]

I understand that superconductivity mainly occurs due to the formation of the Cooper pairs in which electrons, instead of repelling each other, actually attract because one electron actually attracts the positive charges nearby which further attract the the other electron thus establishing a Cooper pair. And since the temperature is very very low the Cooper pair doesn't get enough energy to bump into anything and scatter its energy.

But isn't 150 K too high for the stability and existence of Cooper pairs. Then why do the ceramic materials behave as superconductors?

(Note:- A similar kind of question was asked but it was about what is the maximum temperature possible for a superconductor and if we could explain these ceramic superconductors on the basis of BCS theory. But it was not specifically concerned with my specific question. So pls help!)